# Como ejecutar comando en Java (Runtime.exec) sin que se cuelgue el GUI

Tags: java, exec

Hola a toda la comunidad, vengo con con un problemita que me he encontrado al tratar de hacer una pequeña aplicación java, la cual trata de ejecutar un programa desde una GUI, he leído y buscado información acerca de Runtime() y Process, pero aun así no he podido dar con mi problema.
Tengo una GUI sencila 3 botones, 1 text area para mostrar la salida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el primer botón lo que hago es capturar el directorio donde quiero que se ejecute el programa,
con el segundo ejecuto el programa y el tercero es para pararlo (CTRL + C).

Esa es la idea para esta pequeña app, pero cuando envió a ejecutar(segundo botón) la GUI se queda colgada y debo pararla desde el IDE, desde la consola del mismo IDE puedo ver la salida del cmd (Runtime.exec) y el segundo programa se ejecuta normal pero no logro verlo desde la GUI ya que esta se queda colgada, este es el codigo del boton 2 que activa la ejecucion del comando:

```
    ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/play.jpg"));
    ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon(imagen.getImage().getScaledInstance(30, 30, 
    Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton(icono);
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textArea.setText("Iniciando MeteorJS\n");
            try {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cd && meteor run",null,new File(getRuta()));
                printResults(p,textArea);//Metodo para ver la salida del programa
                
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println (ioe);
            }
        }
    });
```

Metodo para imprimir la salida del comando:

```
public static void printResults(Process process, JTextArea textarea) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        textarea.append(line+"\n");
        System.out.println(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
}
```

Como les mencione anteriormente, a traves del IDE puedo ver la salida del comando pero no se refleja en la GUI por que la misma se queda pegada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías evitar bloquear el hilo principal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066320/how-do-i-prevent-my-jframe-from-freezing/21066572#21066572

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, con esa información pude ubicarme en la documentación correcta

Answer (score 0):

por si a otra persona le sirve, mi problema lo resolví usando ExecutorService, esto crea un hilo aparte del principal y de esa forma no se cuelga la GUI
Acá el código:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                    executor.submit(() -> {
                        try {
                            textArea.setText("Iniciando MeteorJS . . .\n");
                            proceso = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cd && meteor",null,new File(getRuta()));
                            printResults(proceso,textArea);
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
```